# List Plot of points colored by a list

Tags: plotting, color

I have a list of points, say

```
a = Table[{RandomReal[1], {RandomReal[1], RandomReal[1]}}, {i, 100}]
```

I would like to plot the 2D points in the second column, but colour them using Colorfunction with respect to the first column. I tried

```
Show[ListPlot[a[[All, 2]], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][#1] &)]]]
```

But it didn't work for me? any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: `Graphics[{ColorData["SolarColors"][#1], AbsolutePointSize[10], 
    Point[#2]} & @@@ a, Axes -> True]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci - to scale the `ColorFunction` use `Graphics[{ColorData[{"SolarColors", MinMax[a[[All, 1]]]}][#1], 
    AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[#2]} & @@@ a, Axes -> True]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap each data point with `Style`:

```
ListPlot[Style[#2, ColorData["SolarColors"][#1]] & @@@ a,  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ListPlot[List /@ a[[All, 2]], 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData["SolarColors"] /@ a[[All, 1]]), 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Amazing, thank you; what exactly was wrong with the way I did it?

Comment: @MKF, `ColorFunction -> ColorData["SolarColors"][#1] &` uses the x-coordinate of input data (`a[[All,2]]`) .

Comment: ah so it wasn't calling on the first column? got it, thanks!

Comment: OK, is there a way to fix the colour scale to MinMax of a[[All,1]]? Eg in case of SolarColors so min is red, max is yellow?

Comment: @MKF - ColorData[{"SolarColors", MinMax[a[[All, 1]]]}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon when I tried to implement it now it no longer shows spectrum of colours, I was hoping it would normalise the colours

Comment: @MKF - `ListPlot[Style[#2, 
    ColorData[{"SolarColors", MinMax[a[[All, 1]]]}][#1]] & @@@ a, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"SolarColors", MinMax[a[[All, 1]]]}]]`

Comment: @MKF - Or `ListPlot[List /@ a[[All, 2]], 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData[{"SolarColors", MinMax[a[[All, 1]]]}] /@ 
    a[[All, 1]]), BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"SolarColors", MinMax[a[[All, 1]]]}]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you very much, these work great!